# how to show multiple errors in catch clause

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show 2 different error messages. If the user hasn't verified their email, it'll show verification error. If their login info is wrong, it'll show credentials error.

When I do the following with an unverified account, my code skips the verification error and only shows the credentials error even if the login details are correct.

What's a way around this if I can't have multiple catch clauses?

```
....

    .then((data) => {
      const verified = data.emailVerified;

      if (verified === true) {
        return data.user.getIdToken();
      } else if (verified === false ) {
        return res.staus(401).json({ general: "Please verify email and try again."})
      }
    })
    .then((token) => {
      return res.json({
        token,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ general: "Wrong credentials, please try again." });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because you probably check credentials before checking verification.
for showing several errors, you can initiate an array for holding errors,
in each step if some error happens you push the error into the array.
At the end, you check if the array is empty you send success response, but if there are errors you send the errors.